# How to design multiple views in iPhone

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller

I am making code for iPhone. My first screen has only one button with text Menu. When user will click on this button next screen is coming with multiple navigation bar.Each Navigation bar has their own Text information which are being selected after clicking on any Navigation bar.

How i should to design it for iPhone ? Please give me concept. Should i take multiple views ? If i have multiple views how will i hide and show on button click event ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to adapt your user interface to comply to how Apple wants an app to work, look, and feel - or make your own custom viewcontrollers. Even then, you might not get the exact behavior you want.

My hottest tip is to look at similar apps on appstore and see how they are navigated.

I don't get a picture in my mind from your description, but it seems you want what is called "drill down". This is best done with tableViews.

You can't have multiple navigation controllers on the same "screen"; it doesn't work like that on the iPhone. Instead, what you have is one single Navigation controller, that controls the pushing of views. You decide which sub-view to push depending on which selection the user makes, and the Navigation controller handles the rest of the interaction with the user to let him or her navigate between the views.

Example structure:

```
Window-based app
+-MainWindow.xib
| +-First view with button
| +-UINavigationController
+-tableview1.xib
+-tableview2.xib
+-any more views you need.
```

Make the app delegate a `<UINavigationControllerDelegate>` and declare `navCt *UINavigationController`, and connect it in Interface Builder. You can then write a pushVC method, which takes as argument a UIViewController *vc. It does a `[navCt pushViewController:vc animated:YES];`

Connect the button to an IBAction, which then calls the method in the app delegate, `[PushVC myVC]`, where myVC refers to any viewcontroller in your app, in this case table view 1.

In this table, on `didSelectRow...` event you can use the same method to push the sub-view table view 2.

I think this is minimum code if you are unsure about iPhone app design. Either way, I hope it gives some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

You should read about UINavigationController, UITabBarController, UIViewController.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

You almost always make one view pr. viewcontroller.